# How resize whole window when I drag window with mouse

Tags: wpf, resize

I'm new with WPF controls, before I worked with WinForms applications, and there if I put anchor on control and put dock on container all works smoothly but here I have struggle where I mistake?

```
<Window x:Class="ChatApp.Client.ClientWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChatApp.Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Client" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <GroupBox Header="Client" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5, 0, 5, 0">Address:</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Width="80"></TextBox>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 5, 0">Port:</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtPort" Width="80"></TextBox>
                        <Button x:Name="btnConnect" Margin="430, 0, 5, 0" Content="Connect" Width="80" Click="btnConnect_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <GroupBox Header="Chat" Width="650" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtConversation" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <GroupBox Header="Users" Width="135" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbUsers" Height="Auto" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have three group box top dock, second left dock and last one is for right dock.
When I want to resize form with mouse right group box doesn't want to stretch when
I resize form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout seems very over complicated - are you just trying to clone what you did in Winforms in WPF?

- It doesn't make any sense to have StackPanels or a Grid with only one child control each.
- Try replacing your DockPanel with appropriately sized Grid Rows and Columns.
- The GroupBoxes won't resize if you hard code their widths.
- There's no need to define an ItemTemplate for the ListBox just to display a single string.

Something like the following would be a good starting point for your layout.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="135" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GroupBox Header="Client" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Width="80" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Port:" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPort" Width="80" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Button x:Name="btnConnect" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Connect" Width="80" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
  
    <GroupBox Header="Chat" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtConversation" AcceptsReturn="True" />
    </GroupBox>
  
    <GroupBox Header="Users" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbUsers" />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: sorry for waiting my response this is great, as I said I'm new with WPF, can you recommend some quality youtube channel or any other resource, or building good WPF UI depends on experience? Thank you this is what I wanted :)